# On View click inside a RecyclerView row change the state of other rows inside the same RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an `ImageView`inside every row of my `RecyclerView`. I set an `setOnClickListener` inside method `onBindViewHolder()` of my `Adapter` so each time this `ImageView`is clicked something happens.

But the problem is that I need to change the state of other rows inside the same `RecyclerView`. But they are not the current row at method `onBindViewHolder()`.

Is there any way to from method `onBindViewHolder()`change the state of `ImageView`in another row that is not the current one, if I know the position/index of the other row I want to change?

Comment: You should modify your model data and call your adapter to redraw the entire list can that fix your needs?.

Comment: @Nanoc, How would I do it calling `this.notifyDataSetChange` from method `onBindViewHolder()`, inside the Adapter??

Comment: Are you setting a **new** `OnClickListener` in every `onBindViewHolder()` or are you using one object for all your items inside your `RecyclerView.Adapter`?

Comment: @Jessi exactly, that should do the job.

Comment: @Nanoc, this seems to be working I'll be back with any updates. Feels like a workaround to my use case but anyways it seems to be working! :) thanks! brb with updates once I finish my problem

Comment: Feel like a workaround because you should not perform any logic inside an Adapter, its intended to just draw each row of the list, you should use onItemClickListener on the entire list instead of clickListeners for each image

Comment: @Nanoc, hey nanoc sorry for late reply so I followed you advice and moved click listener out from adapter and inside activity now I solved my problem thanks to your input if you want to put that as an answer I can upvote and accept your answer. It seems that using a particular view inside the recyclerview with a clicklistener for my particular use case was just messing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is for example creating a `CustomView` for example `MyRelativeLayout`as a wrapper of the item in RecyvlerView, that extends the view  you need to change, once the user clicks the view this `MyRelativeLayout`you can have a method for example isClicked(boolean) so you put it isclicked(true) and then `myAdapter.notifiyDataSetChanged()`.And then you can decide what to do to you imageView, for example if `MyRelativeLayout` `isClicked() == true` then change its drawable to whatever yo need or something like that.

hope this helps!